# R: draw a line on the same boxplot graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I try to display a line on top of a boxplot graph with the x made from factor.

This code work well:

```
x <- c(91,92,93,125,123,140)
y <- c(200,260,220,300,350,360)
d1 <- data.frame(x=x,y=y)
d1$f1 = factor(round(d1$x/10))
qplot(f1,y,data=d1,geom="boxplot")
d2<-data.frame(x2=c(90,140),y2=c(210,320))
qplot(x2,y2,data=d2,geom="line")
```

But when i try to add the line to the graph...

```
qplot(f1,y,data=d1,geom="boxplot") + geom_line(data = d2, aes(x = x2, y=y2))
```

To see my results: http://jeb-files.s3.amazonaws.com/Clipboard01.jpg

How do I manage to have my line align with my boxplot?

Thanks!

Comment: This is "normal" behavior for ggplot based on what you fed it. Why did you convert x into a factor? The x-axis as the factor now is represented internally as integer values 1 - 3. So plotting a line with x-values 90 thru 140 doesn't make much sense. If you change `x2 = c(1,3)` then the components of the plot will be "aligned" though I'm skeptical of the meaning of either of these. What's the bigger picture question you are trying to answer here?

Comment: What I want is to group the x value, so I use a factor!! Is there another way? The big picture is that I have data that I want to display as a boxplot and overlay an equation curve on it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `boxplot` requires the x-values to be factors, whereas a `geom_line` requires the x-values to be numeric. You can get what you want by modifying the `geom_line` call so that the `x` value is defined as the numeric version of the *ordered* factor obtained from `round(x2/10)`:

```
qplot( f1,y,data=d1,geom="boxplot") +
 geom_line(data = d2, aes(x = as.numeric(ordered(round(x2/10))), y=y2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help! It's better than what I have done so far, but is it possible to change the x axis for the box plot and not for the line? Because, with my real data, I have this: [link](http://jeb-files.s3.amazonaws.com/Clipboard02.jpg) . The red line is normally a curve.