# Boxplot and regression curves for multiple groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I would like to make plot to compare the growth of different groups of trees.

```
library(MASS)
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(grofit)

# Create groups as areas
Loblolly$Area = round(as.integer(as.character((Loblolly$Seed)))/10)
# factors for boxplot
Loblolly$fArea = factor(Loblolly$Area)
Loblolly$fAge  = factor(Loblolly$age)

# Regression curve fitting
fHeight <- nls(height ~ gompertz(age,as,x1,x2), start=list(as=60,x1=1,x2=10), 
               data = ddply(Loblolly, c("age"), summarise, height = mean(height))
)

# A separate data frame for draw the fitted curves
age <- 1:25
lHeight <- predict(fHeight, list(age=age))
dfLine <- data.frame(age, lHeight)

ggplot(data=Loblolly, aes(x=fAge, y=height, fill=fArea)) +
  geom_jitter(colour="lightgray") +
  geom_boxplot()
```

I can create boxplots like this one:

[image: HeightChart]

But I would like to fit separate fitting curves for each fArea groups and place those curves to the plot over the boxplots.

When I use the "fill" option to present groups of parameters as boxplots, I can't use another data.frame for the "geom_line" overlay.

How can I present the fitted gompertz functions as geom_line for each group ?

Comment: Can you provide some data (i.e. dput of Loblolly)?

Comment: Loblolly is in the standard datasets library.

Comment: Ah sorry, thought it's the species you're working with. So the problem is generating a curve for each fArea, or combining geom_line and geom_boxplot, or both?

Comment: I am working with my own dataset, but the content is the same as it is in this sample. The problem is to create the fitting curves for each  groups and present it on the plot. The important questions are, how to keep the list of fitting curves, how to convert them to point lists, and how to combine the geom_line with the boxplots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have the same values for `age` for each `fArea`, the fitted lines will be the same for each `fArea` as your model stands right now.  If you want different fits per group, you'll need to fit separate models per `fArea` first.  There are many ways to do this, one example is at [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-September/141393.html).  This stores a model for each group in a list.

I ended up making the summary dataset so it was ordered by `fArea`, which made it easier for me to add the predictions by `fArea` to `Lob2`.

```
# Make a summary dataset, ordered by fArea
Lob2 = ddply(Loblolly, .(fArea, age), summarize, height = mean(height))

# Function to fit the model by group
f = function(s) nls(height ~ gompertz(age,as,x1,x2), start=list(as=60,x1=1,x2=10), 
               data =  Lob2, subset = Lob2$fArea == s)

# Fit the model by group, save as a list
mods = sapply(levels(Lob2$fArea), f, simplify = FALSE)
```

Then I make predictions for each model in the list with `lapply`, using the data used in the fit for the predictions (this is the default in `predict`) and add these to `Lob2`.  A downside of this approach (in my mind, anyway) is that the order of the dataset I add the predictions to matters so I had to be careful.

```
Lob2$lHeight = unlist(lapply(mods, predict))
```

To add continuous lines to a graph that has a factor on the x axis is a bit awkward.  I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181155/r-draw-a-line-on-the-same-boxplot-graph) that shows how this can be done.  However, this method makes the fitted curves a bit less smooth than might be ideal.  Maybe skipping the boxplots and coloring the points by `fArea` is a reasonable alternative?

```
ggplot(data = Loblolly, aes(x = fAge, y = height, fill = fArea)) +
  geom_jitter(colour="lightgray") +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_line(data = Lob2, aes(x = as.numeric(ordered((age)), y = lHeight, color = fArea))
```

**EDIT** to add making predictions from another dataset

Here is one way to make predictions from a new dataset on a list of models.  Because you would like to graph each `fArea` model separately, it's convenient to keep `fArea` in the new dataset.  I again keep the new dataset in order by `fArea`.

```
# Predict with new data.frame (keeping in order by fArea again)
newdat = expand.grid(age = 1:25, fArea = levels(Lob2$fArea))
```

Now I use `lapply` again, to go through each `level` of `fArea` and make predictions from the each `fArea` model using the appropriate subset of `newdat`.  I add the predictions to `newdat` for ease of graphing.  The dataset must be in order by `fArea` for this to work right as it is coded.

```
newdat$lHeight = unlist(lapply(levels(Lob2$fArea), function(x) {
    predict(mods[[x]], newdata = newdat[newdat$fArea == x,]) } ))
```

You may find you have difficulties plotting this as a continuous line on top of an x-axis that is a factor based on 6 values - that's why I focused on making predictions for only your original data.  An alternative would be to get rid of the boxplots and color both points and lines by the grouping variable.

```
ggplot(data = Loblolly, aes(x = age, y = height, color = fArea)) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = .5)) +
  geom_line(data = newdat, aes(y = lHeight))
```

Comment: `Lob2$lHeight = unlist(lapply(mods, predict))` will predict the curve  only in the original measurement positions (6 x positions). But the predict function accept a third list argument as estimation positiones. Can I use predict(fHeight, lAges) for the lines someway ?

Comment: @jsheperd Yes, you can do this in a variety of ways, the easiest being `lapply(mods, predict, data.frame(age = 1:25))`.  See my edit for a more complicated alternative to help keep organized for graphing.